# For my flight, can I provide my old passport number until my new passport arrives?

Tags: passports

For a flight to the Philippines, is it a problem if I submit my old passport number when I booked the ticket? I applied to renew my passport, in order to make a name change. I have to book a ticket now, but my new passport has not yet been received. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

If your personal details (such as name, date of birth, etc.) will remain the same, then you can provide your new passport at the checkin desk without issue.

The API (Advanced Passenger Information) that includes among other things your passport information can be updated as long as the flight has not departed.

If your old passport contains a valid visa, then you **must carry it with you** along with your new passport and present both to immigration (if required, for your destination).

Comment: The question explicitly about a name change.

Comment: The question only says "is it a problem if I submit my old passport number". It doesn't say, that the old name was provided in the booking as well. So if anything, the question is unclear in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, **no**, it's not a problem, assuming nothing else has changed (meaning you booked your ticket with the new name, and do not need to change this as well).  You can give them the new passport number when you check in.

Comment: Unless you need a visa, of course, and the passport number is required.

Comment: @MarkMayo Sure, but that's another question, and many (but not all) countries accept valid visas in old passports.

Comment: yep I'm not disagreeing with your answer, just adding a footnote :)

Comment: The question is explicitly about a name change.

Comment: @phoog If they booked the original ticket with the new name, "nothing else has changed" and my advice still stands.  But I'll clarify.