# Do I need to give a real passport number at the time of booking for a flight from HKG to the United States?

Tags: usa, passports, international-travel, hong-kong, singapore-airlines

I am planning a trip to Hong Kong in June.  When I tried to book my return flight (a direct flight from HKG to SFO) on Singapore Airlines's website, it requires that I enter my passport information (number, expiration date, etc.).  My passport is currently being renewed and I don't have this information yet, but I'm hoping to book the flight now while the fares are reasonably low.  My friend, who booked the same flight, seems to be able to change his passport information for his booking without issue.

My question is: Can I just put in made-up information for now, and then enter in the real information when I get my new passport?  What can go wrong?

Comment: My question differs slightly (I plan on giving the correct information eventually), but I think the information in the linked question answers my question.  It sounds like it doesn't really matter, so I can proceed as planned and put in some made-up information for now.  I guess I was just wondering if Singapore Airlines is going to do anything with my made-up passport number besides keep it on file.  In any case, thanks!

Comment: They do pass it to immigration in the US but it doesn't matter as those details would be updated anyway when you scan your passport at the boarding gate. Likewise US immigration doesn't care in the slightest about what you give to the airline.

Comment: Is the information really mandatory? Most such processes I know of either request those details at a later stage (after booking has been completed) and/or make it optional during the booking process. There may be a “skip” or “later” link not very visible somewhere on the page.

Comment: @jcaron "Is the information really mandatory?" -- That's my question.  The Singapore Airlines website is forcing me to provide it, which is weird.  It's a mandatory field in their application.

Comment: @nukeguy that's a bit unusual at this stage in my experience. I recommend you don't put a random number in there, use something like "willprovidelater" instead for instance.

Comment: I believe your real question is "Does Singapore Airlines allow me to amend my passport number after the booking has been made, free of charge?".

Comment: @KH.Lee The answer to that question is yes -- my friend is able to change his passport number on his booking without any problems. 
 My question is more about whether or not there are any consequences for not including it (i.e., either putting down made up information or putting "willprovidelater") at the initial time of booking even though it is a required field.  From the information you guys have provided, it seems like the answer to my question is no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For UK/USA bound flights, are details entered during online check-in, such as date of birth or passport number ever checked by airlines/immigration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da) and [For my flight, can I provide my old passport number until my new passport arrives?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90148/for-my-flight-can-i-provide-my-old-passport-number-until-my-new-passport-arrive)

Comment: @Giorgio Thanks! I forgot to update this, but I think the second question you linked to pretty much answers it.  I went on the trip and it was fine.   I think they just disregard anything you entered before once you check in.

Comment: @nukeguy good to hear all went well; I don't know that the info is ignored, more that the valid data has to be there 72 hours before departure, for the data that appears in the Advance Passenger Information System (APIS) transmitted to the gov't.